# How can gpiotest fail on all GPIO pins?

Tags: gpio

When trying to pin down a [communications issue with a GPS module attached to my Pi's UART,](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/613983/why-is-the-adafruit-gps-breakout-board-no-longer-receiving-after-a-couple-of-yea) I disconnected all peripherals performed a test of all GPIOs using `gpiotest`. This is what came out:

```
pi@autoradio:/import/valen/autoradio $ sudo pigpiod
pi@autoradio:/import/valen/autoradio $ ./gpiotest                 
This program checks the Pi's (user) gpios.

The program reads and writes all the gpios.  Make sure NOTHING
is connected to the gpios during this test.

The program uses the pigpio daemon which must be running.

To start the daemon use the command sudo pigpiod.

Press the ENTER key to continue or ctrl-C to abort...

Testing...
Write 1 to gpio 2 failed.
Pull up on gpio 2 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 3 failed.
Pull up on gpio 3 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 4 failed.
Pull up on gpio 4 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 5 failed.
Pull up on gpio 5 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 6 failed.
Pull up on gpio 6 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 7 failed.
Pull up on gpio 7 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 8 failed.
Pull up on gpio 8 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 9 failed.
Pull up on gpio 9 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 10 failed.
Pull up on gpio 10 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 11 failed.
Pull up on gpio 11 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 12 failed.
Pull up on gpio 12 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 13 failed.
Pull up on gpio 13 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 14 failed.
Pull up on gpio 14 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 15 failed.
Pull up on gpio 15 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 16 failed.
Pull up on gpio 16 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 17 failed.
Pull up on gpio 17 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 18 failed.
Pull up on gpio 18 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 19 failed.
Pull up on gpio 19 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 20 failed.
Pull up on gpio 20 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 21 failed.
Pull up on gpio 21 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 22 failed.
Pull up on gpio 22 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 23 failed.
Pull up on gpio 23 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 24 failed.
Pull up on gpio 24 failed.
Pull down on gpio 25 failed.
Pull down on gpio 26 failed.
Pull down on gpio 27 failed.
Pull up on gpio 27 failed.
Skipped non-user gpios: 0 1 28 29 30 31 
Tested user gpios: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
Failed user gpios: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
```

Does this mean that my Pi's (it's a Model 3B+ with raspbian Buster on it) GPIOs have been fried, or have I done something wrong then operating the test? I haven't used the GPIOs for some time, but before that, everything had worked save for the GPS module, which returned no data.

**UPDATE:** I gave the Pi another try with the `gpio` utility, which comes with WiringPi, and this came out:

```
pi@autoradio:~ $ gpio readall
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3B+-+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   |  1 || 2  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   2 |   8 |   SDA.1 | ALT0 | 0 |  3 || 4  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   3 |   9 |   SCL.1 | ALT0 | 0 |  5 || 6  |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   4 |   7 | GPIO. 7 |   IN | 0 |  7 || 8  | 0 | ALT5 | TxD     | 15  | 14  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   |  9 || 10 | 0 | ALT5 | RxD     | 16  | 15  |
 |  17 |   0 | GPIO. 0 |  OUT | 0 | 11 || 12 | 0 | ALT0 | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18  |
 |  27 |   2 | GPIO. 2 |   IN | 0 | 13 || 14 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  22 |   3 | GPIO. 3 |  OUT | 0 | 15 || 16 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 4 | 4   | 23  |
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   | 17 || 18 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 5 | 5   | 24  |
 |  10 |  12 |    MOSI | ALT0 | 0 | 19 || 20 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   9 |  13 |    MISO | ALT0 | 0 | 21 || 22 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 6 | 6   | 25  |
 |  11 |  14 |    SCLK | ALT0 | 0 | 23 || 24 | 0 | ALT0 | CE0     | 10  | 8   |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 25 || 26 | 0 | ALT0 | CE1     | 11  | 7   |
 |   0 |  30 |   SDA.0 |   IN | 0 | 27 || 28 | 0 | IN   | SCL.0   | 31  | 1   |
 |   5 |  21 | GPIO.21 |  OUT | 0 | 29 || 30 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   6 |  22 | GPIO.22 |   IN | 0 | 31 || 32 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.26 | 26  | 12  |
 |  13 |  23 | GPIO.23 |   IN | 0 | 33 || 34 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  19 |  24 | GPIO.24 | ALT0 | 0 | 35 || 36 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.27 | 27  | 16  |
 |  26 |  25 | GPIO.25 |   IN | 0 | 37 || 38 | 0 | ALT0 | GPIO.28 | 28  | 20  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 39 || 40 | 0 | ALT0 | GPIO.29 | 29  | 21  |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3B+-+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: What had you done before? What have you done to test the hardware independent of OS & attached hardware? Did you attempt ANY testing before asking a question?

Comment: Sure I have! :-P There used to be quite a bunch of hardware attached to my Pi. One of them was a GPS module attached to the Pi's UART, which ceased working some time ago. The module did send data to the Pi, but the Pi received nothing. And it was not the wiring! See my original issue: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/613983/why-is-the-adafruit-gps-breakout-board-no-longer-receiving-after-a-couple-of-yea

Answer (score 1):

All the GPIO appear to have failed.

All you can hope for is that pigpio has made a mistake.

Try testing a switch or turning a LED on and off with another GPIO library.

Answer (score 0):

I gave `gpiotest` another try, and the results were exactly the same ones. So the only thing I was left with to to was to purchase another Pi move the SD card from the broken one — and on the new Pi, everything worked fine.

So it was really a hardware failure.

Answer (score -1):

After "gpiotest", I got the following responses:
Skipped non-user gpios: 0 1 28 29 30 31 
Tested user gpios: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
Failed user gpios: 14 15 17 18 19 20 21 22 25 27

But the real situation is not quite same as the failure messages above!
1.I can still successfully use 14。21，22，23，25，27 for input, why?
2.GPIO 17、18、19、20 don't exist(see "gpio realall") in wPi，how failed?!

Can someone let me know the answers?
Thank you in advance!

Bseides, although falilure message appaeras, you can connect a LED for a test for approval!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/122553)